# Update inside React useState setter being called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update something inside the scope of the useState setter.  This works as I would expect in the following codepen example:

[Update value outside of state variable](https://codepen.io/nfcarbone/pen/Vwmddvx)

But as implemented in my application the `insideCallCount` is getting called twice for every `toggleCell` call. See below for the relevant portion:

```
  const callCount = useRef(0);
  const insideCallCount = useRef(0);
  const toggleCell = (i) => {
    callCount.current += 1;
    setPattern((pattern) => {
      let newPattern = deepCopyPattern(pattern);
      newPattern[i][selectedSound].on = !newPattern[i][selectedSound].on;
      insideCallCount.current += 1;
      return newPattern;
    });
    console.log('callCount: ', callCount.current);
    console.log('insideCallCount: ', insideCallCount.current);
  };
```

The console readout looks like this after I 'toggle' a button several times:

```
callCount:  1
insideCallCount:  0
callCount:  2
insideCallCount:  2
callCount:  3
insideCallCount:  4
callCount:  4
insideCallCount:  6
callCount:  5
insideCallCount:  8
callCount:  6
insideCallCount:  10
```

My understanding this has something to do with the fact that it's wrapped in a function definition.  I tried wrapping the whole thing in a useCallback with values to watch inside the dependency array but that didn't help.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As is usually the case when things start unexpectedly reoccuring in a React App: make sure `StrictMode` is disabled. You'll find it wrapped around `<App/>` by default in your `index.js` file on new create-react-app builds. I can only reproduce/fix this by creating a new project with it and then removing it.

Whether you want to leave it off is up to you. It will not be included when you create a production build and can help identify potential problems in your application. In the course of testing your code it will double-invoke various lifecycle methods (in class components) and hooks (in functional components) to highlight where unexpected side-effects may occur in *future* versions of React.

For this reason, the documentation recommends *not* performing side effects in any of the following:

- Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
- Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
- Function component bodies
- State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
- Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

This list is taken from the [documentation on StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

Comment: A `useEffect` would be the obvious place. It does mean that the ref will be updated significantly later than in your example; state will be set, then the component will rerender, then the effect will be fired to update the ref.

Comment: Also, again quoting from the docs, this is only to prepare users of React for the upcoming (optional) concurrent mode in which side-effects in the listed scenarios might actually be commited multiple times, or not at all. It's not a concern in the current React builds as I understand it

Comment: The first sentence in the useEffect documentation says: "The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components:". 
 https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @NickCarbone: I don't understand what you mean. Hooks are only meant for function components.